# Estimating error between Taylor series and $\tanh$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that:

$\mid \tanh(x) - P_4(x) \mid \leq 0.005 \qquad for \quad \mid x \mid < 1/2$

Where $P_4$ is the taylor series expansion with degree 4:

$P_4(x)=x-\frac{1}{3}x^3$

I've established that:

$\tanh(x) < x \qquad for \quad x \in (0, \infty) $

and that $\tanh(x)-P_4(x)$ is increasing on $(0, \infty)$

I now need to show that:

$\tanh \frac{1}{2} - P_4(\frac{1}{2}) \leq 0.005$

using the fact that $e < 2.72$, and use this to proof the result:

$\mid \tanh(x) - P_4(x) \mid \leq 0.005 \qquad for \quad \mid x \mid < 1/2$

I'm unsure how i can use this estimate for $e$ as i don't have a lower bound for $e$, so i can't change $e$ with a fractions that are bigger and smaller. I'm also not sure how i can use this to show that:

$\mid \tanh(x) - P_4(x) \mid \leq 0.005 \quad when \quad -\frac{1}{2}<x<0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\tanh(1/2) = \frac{\exp(1/2) - \exp(-1/2)}{\exp(1/2) + \exp(-1/2)} = \frac{e-1}{e+1} $$
and  (if $k < 1$) $$ \frac{e-1}{e+1} \le k \ \text{iff}\ e-1 \le k (e+1) ]\ \text{iff}\ e < \frac{1+k}{1-k} $$

EDIT: You already established that $\tanh(x) - P_4(x)$ is increasing, and of course $\tanh(0) = P_4(0) = 0$, so you want to show $\tanh(1/2) - P_4(1/2) \le .005$, i.e. $\tanh(1/2) \le .005 + P_4(1/2) = 0.46333\ldots$, call this $k$.  As shown in the paragraph above, this is
equivalent to $e \le (1+k)/(1-k) = 2.7267\ldots$.  And since you know
$e < 2.72$, that does it.

As for $-1/2 < x < 0$, note that both $\tanh$ and $P_4$ are odd functions.

Comment: Can you expand on how to use this to establish the inequality?

Answer (score 2):

From the taylor series of $\tanh(x)$ for $|x|<1$,
$$
|\tanh(x)|<\left|x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}\right|.
$$
If, $x>0$,
$$
\tanh(x)<x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15} \\
\implies\tanh(x)-P_4(x)<\frac{2x^5}{15}. \\
\therefore \tanh\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-P_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)<\frac{1}{15\cdot 16}.
$$
If x <0,
$$
\tanh(x)>x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15} \\
\implies \tanh(x)-P_4(x)>\frac{2x^5}{15}. \\
\therefore \tanh\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)-P_4\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)>-\frac{1}{15\cdot 16}.
$$
$\tanh(x)-P_4(x)$ is increasing in $\mathbb{R}$, thus
$$
-\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{1}{2}\\
\implies \tanh\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)-P_4\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)<\tanh(x)-P_4(x)<\tanh\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-P_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
\implies-\frac{1}{15\cdot 16}
<\tanh(x)-P_4(x)<\frac{1}{15\cdot 16} \\
\implies |\tanh(x)-P_4(x)|<\frac{1}{15\cdot 16}\approx 0.004167 < 0.005.
$$
Thus, $|\tanh(x)-P_4|<0.005$, whenever $|x|<1/2.$